# Most effective way to retrieve data from computer to website | C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xmlhttprequest

Sorry if the question is simple or incomprehensible!

I am creating a license-based website (NodeJS (TypeScript) + React), now I need to check if there are some license files from the user's computer.

I did a lot of searching on Google and found WCF. And I created a localhost as follows.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "get/mac",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string PostMacAddress(MachineMac data);
}

public class MachineMac
{
    public string MacineMacAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And host config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

    <bindings>
      <!--<wsHttpBinding>-->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"     sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <!--<transport clientCredentialType="None" />-->
      </security>
      <!--<reliableSession enabled="true" />-->
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <!--</wsHttpBinding>-->

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttp" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <!--<transport clientCredentialType="None" />-->
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>

  <service name="App.Services.Service">
    <endpoint address ="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" contract="App.Services.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3366" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- rest api-->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The program is now running and sending the user's mac address.

If I send a request (ReactJS) to localhost from the real server, it doesn't work. It only sends a request to the host I created through the browser when it is on my computer.
My ReactJS (Axios request as following):
[ReactJS Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEBY6.png) 
And i getting as follow error!
[My Error as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1xoC.png)

My question is, what other ways are there to retrieve information from a user’s computer through a browser? Or is it possible to do it the way I do? The example above I created for verification only. I need to know if the user's computer has the file I need. Let's say I need to be able to check from within the `C:\\MyAppLicense` directory.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to call wcf from JavaScript code? Can you explain `it doesn't work`? Do you see any error in browser's network trace?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i celled using axios, i edited my question.